# Parsing date periods and summarise days

Tags: sas

I'm asking support to manage something I'm able to manage with R but not in SAS and I must in SAS.

Suppose to deal with the following dataset:

> ```
>           ID           Start         End        Label
>        subjectA      01/01/2020   15/01/2020   holidays
>        subjectA      16/01/2020   20/01/2020   holidays
>        subjectB      01/05/2020   30/05/2020   holidays
>        subjectB      01/06/2020   07/06/2020   holidays
>        subjectC      01/02/2020   01/02/2020   work_permit
>        subjectD      01/03/2020   01/09/2020   maternity     
>        subjectE      03/01/2020   09/01/2020   disease
>        subjectE      11/01/2020   13/01/2020   disease
>        subjectF      12/02/2020   12/02/2020   work_permit
>        subjectG      11/09/2020   20/09/2020   course
>        .......       ........     ........     ..........
> ```

I need the following:
for repeated entries after sorting Start and End so that the previous Start-End represents a time period before the subsequent:

1. if the difference between the Start and End is 1 day for the same repeated entry (ID) then sum the number of days, otherwise (>1 days) count without sum. This for holidays, maternity and disease.
2. if the difference between the Start and End is 0 days (consecutive) for the same repeated entry (ID) then sum the number of days, otherwise if > 1 days sum without count. This for holidays, maternity and disease.

For not repeated entries:

1. count the days;
2. count 1 day if the same Start-End.

Desired output:

> ```
>           ID           Days      Label           Flag     
>        subjectA         20      holidays      summarised
>        subjectB         37      holidays      summarised
>        subjectC         1      work_permit    single_day
>        subjectD        184      maternity   consecutive_not_summarized     
>        subjectE         19       disease       summarised
>        subjectF         1      work_permit     single_day
>        subjectG        10        course     consecutive_not_summarized 
>        .......       ........     ........     ..........
> ```

For ranges involving February, it was of 29 days. Moreover there might be more than two periods per repeated record.

Sorry it seems to be complex. I have no idea how to start writing this in SAS and so I need support and guide.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I cannot figure out what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to avoid double counting a date when it is listed as both the end of one period and the start of the next?  Also is it ever possible to have two periods that overlap by more than just that one middle date?

Comment: I'm trying to sum the days of duplicated records only when there is no more than one day of difference between the end of the previous period and the start of the next period (as an example [not-shown in the request] the first period ends on 3/06 and the subsequent period starts on 5/06. The sum will be applied also in the case: end on 3/06 and start on 4/06, so no days in-between). Note that for the same record I can have 4, 5, 6, etc periods. About the second question it is not possible because data are referred to employers that are or present or absent at work and are prospective.

Comment: What have you tried? Use LAG() to get the previous value of a variable. Use BY to identify groups of series. I would go through and add a group flag to identify a unique series of holidays by dates. Summarize them using proc means and use the N to see ifs a summarized, single_day, consecutive_not_summarized category. It's a data step, proc means and a another data step.

Comment: Thank you for advices and guidelines. I will try although it seems so hard. It is not a task for beginners although I have to do it.

Comment: I still don't understand.  Perhaps you can update the examples to show some of the issues you are talking about because I do not see any in the current data.  It does not help that you are displaying the dates in DMY order (or MDY order) which is confusing for half the audience.

Comment: Is Subject B correct? There are 31 days in May and June 1, so that's not a consecutive sequence....

Comment: Same for E, that's 2 days difference in disease, not 1...

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the days in the period just subtract start from end and add one.  To calculate the gap between periods use the LAG() of end.  Make sure to reset the calculated gap when starting a new ID.

```
data have;
  input ID :$20. Start :ddmmyy. End :ddmmyy. Label :$20.;
  format start end yymmdd10.;
cards;
subjectA 01/01/2020 15/01/2020 holidays
subjectA 16/01/2020 20/01/2020 holidays
subjectB 01/05/2020 30/05/2020 holidays
subjectB 01/06/2020 07/06/2020 holidays
subjectC 01/02/2020 01/02/2020 work_permit
subjectD 01/03/2020 01/09/2020 maternity
subjectE 03/01/2020 09/01/2020 disease
subjectE 11/01/2020 13/01/2020 disease
subjectF 12/02/2020 12/02/2020 work_permit
subjectG 11/09/2020 20/09/2020 course
;
data days;
  set have;
  by id;
  days = end - start + 1 ;
  gap = start - lag(end);
  if first.id then gap=. ;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs       ID            Start           End    Label          days    gap

  1    subjectA    2020-01-01    2020-01-15    holidays         15     .
  2    subjectA    2020-01-16    2020-01-20    holidays          5     1
  3    subjectB    2020-05-01    2020-05-30    holidays         30     .
  4    subjectB    2020-06-01    2020-06-07    holidays          7     2
  5    subjectC    2020-02-01    2020-02-01    work_permit       1     .
  6    subjectD    2020-03-01    2020-09-01    maternity       185     .
  7    subjectE    2020-01-03    2020-01-09    disease           7     .
  8    subjectE    2020-01-11    2020-01-13    disease           3     2
  9    subjectF    2020-02-12    2020-02-12    work_permit       1     .
 10    subjectG    2020-09-11    2020-09-20    course           10     .
```

But I cannot figure out what you want to do when the gap is larger than 1 and your example data and results do not really provide any real guidance. For most cases you seem to just want the sum of the days whether or not there is a large gap.

```
proc summary data=days;
  by id label;
  var days;
  output out=want sum= ;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs       ID       Label          _TYPE_    _FREQ_    days

 1     subjectA    holidays          0         2        20
 2     subjectB    holidays          0         2        37
 3     subjectC    work_permit       0         1         1
 4     subjectD    maternity         0         1       185
 5     subjectE    disease           0         2        10
 6     subjectF    work_permit       0         1         1
 7     subjectG    course            0         1        10
```

If you want to exclude periods that are more than 1 day after the previous period you could just add a WHERE clause.

```
proc summary data=days;
  where gap < 2;
  by id label;
  var days;
  output out=want sum= ;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs       ID       Label          _TYPE_    _FREQ_    days

 1     subjectA    holidays          0         2        20
 2     subjectB    holidays          0         1        30
 3     subjectC    work_permit       0         1         1
 4     subjectD    maternity         0         1       185
 5     subjectE    disease           0         1         7
 6     subjectF    work_permit       0         1         1
 7     subjectG    course            0         1        10
```

If the goal is not collapse the intervals in periods without gaps then make a new variable to indicate when a new period starts.

```
data days;
  set have;
  by id;
  days = end - start + 1 ;
  gap = start - lag(end);
  period + (gap > 1);
  if first.id then do;
    gap=. ;
    period=1;
  end;
run;

proc summary data=days ;
  by id period label ;
  var days;
  output out=want sum=;
run;
```

Now subjects B and E have two periods and the other examples only one.

Results

```
Obs       ID       period    Label          _TYPE_    _FREQ_    days

 1     subjectA       1      holidays          0         2        20
 2     subjectB       1      holidays          0         1        30
 3     subjectB       2      holidays          0         1         7
 4     subjectC       1      work_permit       0         1         1
 5     subjectD       1      maternity         0         1       185
 6     subjectE       1      disease           0         1         7
 7     subjectE       2      disease           0         1         3
 8     subjectF       1      work_permit       0         1         1
 9     subjectG       1      course            0         1        10
```

Comment: Just to reply to your doubt: "for most cases you seem to just want the sum of the days whether or not there is a large gap", I just want to sum vertically the periods for replicated IDs when they are consecutive (with a maximum delay of 1 day), otherwise just calculate the days horizontally from Start to End.

Comment: So is your ask really about how to collapse the intervals without gaps into single intervals?  Some ID will be reduced to a single observations but those with gaps will still have multiple observations? That is a commonly asked question and should have answers on this forum or SAS communities.

Comment: In a sense, yes meaning: collapse by ID (same) and label (same) only when the next range starts directly after the end of the previous or max 1 day after.

Comment: If the grouping is by ID and LABEL then use BY ID LABEL and FIRST.LABEL in the data step instead of BY ID and FIRST.ID.

Comment: I would recommend creating a custom calendar with company holidays and such and then use INTNX with the custom calendar to find the days difference. Also not sure I agree with your premise, but you can test it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Strong suspicion this won't scale because you're not accounting for weekends/days off allowed at work, ie Statutory holidays, office closures, consecutive days rules doesn't seem applied consistently.

But here's a start. You can modify as needed or update your question with more details. Please include data as a data step in future questions (like what I have in the first step of my answer below).

```
data have;
    input ID : $14. Start : ddmmyy10.      End : ddmmyy10.       Label : $20.;
    format start end date9.;
    cards;
   subjectA      01/01/2020   15/01/2020   holidays
   subjectA      16/01/2020   20/01/2020   holidays
   subjectB      01/05/2020   30/05/2020   holidays
   subjectB      01/06/2020   07/06/2020   holidays
   subjectC      01/02/2020   01/02/2020   work_permit
   subjectD      01/03/2020   01/09/2020   maternity     
   subjectE      03/01/2020   09/01/2020   disease
   subjectE      11/01/2020   13/01/2020   disease
   subjectF      12/02/2020   12/02/2020   work_permit
   subjectG      11/09/2020   20/09/2020   course
   ;
    ;
    ;;
run;

data groups;
    set have;
    by id label notsorted;
    prev_end=lag(end);

    if first.id then
        do;
            group=0;
            call missing(prev_end);
        end;
    
    if first.label or prev_end+1 ne start then
        group+1;
    duration=end-start+1;
run;

proc means data=groups noprint nway;
    class id label group;
    var duration;
    output out=summarized N=Number_Events Sum=Total_Duration;
run;

data want;
    set groups;
    IF n>2 AND LABEL not in ('work_permit', 'maternity') then flag = 'Summarized';
    else if duration = 1 then flag = 'Single Day';
    else flag = 'consecutive_not_summarized';
run;
```

Comment: To reply to your observation: "strong suspicion this won't scale because you're not accounting for weekends/days off allowed at work, ie Statutory holidays, office closures, consecutive days rules doesn't seem applied consistently." It is a good observation. We next have to merge the results with other tables to get more informative data. The idea is: if a worker goes back to work and asks after 1 day again for vacation it is because of a stress related reason.